# Residue field of DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, extension-field, algebraic-curves, local-rings

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and residue field $K = A/\mathfrak{m}$ and suppose that $A$ is also a $k$-algebra. Under what conditions can I say that $K/k$ is a finite field extension?

More specifically, I have a non-singular curve $X$ over a field $k$. For every $P$ the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X, P}$ is a DVR and a $k$-algebra and I would like to show that the residue field $k_P = \mathscr{O}_{X, P}/\mathfrak{m}_{X, P}$ is a finite extension of $k$.

This question comes from trying to understand Definition 3.2 in Isabel Longbottom's note ["Riemann-Roch for nonsingular complete curves"](https://isabel-prime.github.io/files/Riemann-Roch-on-finite-fields.pdf).

Thank you for your time. Any answers or comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: @reuns , thanks for spotting that typo. What do you mean by the second sentence?

Comment: If $E/F$ is a finite extension and $R\subset E$ is a DVR with $E=Frac(R)$ then $S=R\cap F$ is a DVR and $R/m_R$ is a finite extension of $S/m_S$. For curves $E=k(X),F=k(x)$ where $x$ is any non-constant function regular at $P$ and $S/m_S$ is a finite extension of $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about DVRs immediately is the wrong way to solve this problem. The right way is to use the fact that you're dealing with a scheme of finite type over $k$:

Suppose $C$ is our curve and let $U\subset C$ be an affine open subset containing the closed point $p$. Then $k[U]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $\kappa(p)=k[U]/\mathfrak{m}_p$, so the residue field $\kappa(p)$ is a field which is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra. By [Zariski's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma), $\kappa(p)$ is finite over $k$.

The DVR $k(x)[y]_{(y)}$ is an example of a DVR over $k$ which has a residue field which is not finite over $k$ - in general, the local ring of a codimension one subvariety in a normal variety of dimension at least two will furnish many examples of DVRs over $k$ which have a residue field which is not a finite extension of $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is $k[U]$?

Comment: The coordinate algebra of $U$.